# Where I can see Lintian build logs?

Tags: release-management

As a mainly Debian user, I love to see the [PTS](http://packages.qa.debian.org) with several reports about all the packages for Debian repositories, including Lintian reports. I've check out the [Testing Tracker](http://packages.qa.ubuntu.com) but I haven't seen lintian anywhere. The http://lintian.ubuntuwire.org/ page only have Saucy information and seems abandoned.